# UrlFetchApp fetch method fails with 404 error, but same URL works with Curl and browsers

Tags: google-apps-script

If I execute below code, it works fine:

```
curl 'http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/stock/trailing-total-returns.action?&t=DAL&region=usa&culture=en_US&comparisonRemove=true&cur=&ops=clear&ep=true&align=d&annlz=true'
```

I can also execute this URL from any browser and it returns expected results

```
http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/stock/trailing-total-returns.action?&t=DAL&region=usa&culture=en_US&comparisonRemove=true&cur=&ops=clear&ep=true&align=d&annlz=true
```

However, below code fails with error 404.

```
function fetchFromURLTemp() {
  let url = "http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/stock/trailing-total-returns.action?&t=DAL&region=usa&culture=en_US&comparisonRemove=true&cur=&ops=clear&ep=true&align=d&annlz=true";
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': { 'Accept': '*/*' },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*; q = 0.8'
  };

  let httpResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  let status = httpResponse.getResponseCode()
  let urlData = httpResponse.getContentText();
  console.info("Response Status : " + status + ", Response Content : " + urlData)
}
```

It prints following message on the console

```
Response Status : 404, Response Content : The report is no longer supported
```

Can someone please advise what changes I need to get the response.

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing the settings of your script to run on the old "ES5" runtime (Project Settings, uncheck "Enable Chrome V8 runtime").  I had the same error as you until I did that, then it worked.  (The fact that Darpan Sanghavi had to change `let` to `var` was a hint: `let` is not a keyword in the old runtime.)  I'm not sure why it doesn't work under V8--it's likely a bug in the underlying implementation of `UrlFetchApp.fetch`

Comment: Makes perfect sense! I missed pointing out on the runtime version part.

Comment: Thanks @aaron-dunigan-atlee and Darpan Shanghavi ! After I unchecked the option to 'Enable Chrome V8 runtime', I was able to get an expected response from the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me, just change `let` to `var`

```
 function fetchFromURLTemp() {
  var url = "http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/stock/trailing-total-returns.action?&t=DAL&region=usa&culture=en_US&comparisonRemove=true&cur=&ops=clear&ep=true&align=d&annlz=true";
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': { 'Accept': '*/*' },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*; q = 0.8'
  };

  var httpResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var status = httpResponse.getResponseCode()
  var urlData = httpResponse.getContentText();
  Logger.log("Response Status : " + status + ", Response Content : " + urlData)
}
```

Comment: This is really strange! As suggested, I changed all variables from let to var and it still fails with below error:  Response Status : 404, Response Content : The report is no longer supported. I am executing this fetchFromURLTemp function from Google Apps script editor. When you execute this function, does it print complete HTML response on the console? Any idea why it's not working for me. Thanks!